# How do you make a crazy craft server on mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

I'm trying to make a crazy craft server with my friend. I downloaded the server pack download already on the voids wrath website.When i double click the server folder i downloaded, it shows me a bunch files where you can start the server on a certain amount of gb. For example there is a 2,4, 8, 10 and 16 gb you can run the server on. I want to run it on 4 gb, so whenever i double click it, it opens up text edit, and it doesn't start the server. What do I do? It would be very appreciated if someone could help. Thanks :)

By the way I'm running on a mac, not a PC

Comment: Um i tried that but this happens,: Unable to access jarfile minecraft-server1.6.4.jar logout [Process completed]Do u know how to fix it? @ghostmancer

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28858/ghostmancer

Answer (score 1):

The files are script files, and by default they open in TextEdit. To change this, you just need to change what the default program for it is.

Open the "Get Info" dialog for the file, and under the "Open With..." section, there should be an "Other" option. In the menu that appears, choose Terminal to be the new default application.

It should run now. Have fun!

Comment: Um i tried that but this happens,: Unable to access jarfile minecraft-server1.6.4.jar
logout

[Process completed]

Comment: Do u know how to fix it?

Comment: do you know how to fix that?